# How to Fetch PHAssets that only have location data

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the Photos framework for iOS, in order to make a request for a set of `PHAssets` with specific filters, you use the `fetchAssetsWithOptions:options` and pass a `PHFetchOptions` object with the filters wanted.

I'm trying to filter out any `PHAssets` that don't have a location asset metadata object in them, and not entirely sure if it can be done with the `predicate` option on the `PHFetchOptions`. There might be another way to filter out the assets based on if location is present, but I'm not entirely sure on the most efficient way to do this.

```
//Photos fetch
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];

options = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];

PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHFetchOptions_Class/index.html this can't be done using a predicate. The location property of PHAsset can't be used in a predicate/sortDescriptor.

So the only option is to enumerate through the objects of the PHFetchResult and then filter out the ones that do not have location data. This is of course slower than using a predicate but might be still a solution depending on your use case.

Example for using this approach:

```
[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:nil];
    NSMutableArray *filteredAssets = [NSMutableArray new];
    [result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (asset.location != nil) {
            [filteredAssets addObject:asset];
        }
    }];

    //optional - create new Collection/fetchresult with filtered assets
    PHAssetCollection *assetCollectionWithLocation = [PHAssetCollection transientAssetCollectionWithAssets:filteredAssets title:@"Assets with location data"];
    PHFetchResult *filteredResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:assetCollectionWithLocation options:nil];

}];
```